# How can I deal with a non-numerical value for a derivative at $t = 0$ when using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I want to solve two coupled equations with `NDSolve`,

```
t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t], 
x[0] == y[0], x[1] == 1
```

It's easy to see that at `t = 0` the derivative is undetermined, so `NDSolve` fails.

The *Mathematica* help center told me one possibility is to start at a small `ε > 0` instead of 0, and another possibility is to use the option `SolveDelayed -> True` to avoid the singularity in the solved form of the equations.

Unfortunately neither of the methods worked for me. What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try "shooting method":

```
eqn1 = t x'[t] - (-x[t] + y[t]);
eqn2 = t y'[t] - (-5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t]);
sol = NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x[0] == y[0], x[1] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
              Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
                                     {x[1] == 1, y[1] == 2/100 + 91/16000}}];
Plot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

The `"StartingInitialConditions"` above is found by trial and error, despite some warnings generated, the solution is reliable enough:

```
(* Error check *)
Plot[{eqn1, eqn2} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
Plot[{eqn1, eqn2} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
[image]

---

**Edit**

Let me add some explanations about how I found a good initial condition. As I've mentioned in the comment below, what I used is just method of exhaustion… yeah, exhaustion, sounds clumsy but it's really powerful.

First, I define the following function for the realization of the method:

```
ClearAll[try]
SetAttributes[try, Listable]
try[i_] :=(* try[i] = *){i, Quiet@NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x[0] == y[0], x[1] == 1}, 
                           {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
                           "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[1] == 1, y[1] == i}}]};
```

If you add the `try[i] =` in the note into the code, *Mathematica* will remember all the calculated `try[i]` so repetitive computation can be avoided when rechecking, of course this will consume more memory and not that necessary for your case.

We don't know what value will be a proper initial condition, but it's not that hard to guess the approximate extent of it, based on some observations to the equations and boundary conditions, I guess that `y[1]` may be between `-10` and `10`. So I tried:

```
midpoint = 0; step = 1; 
try@Range[midpoint - 10 step, midpoint + 10 step, step] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

All of the trials fail in the middle of the domain of `t`, but one of them stick out to about `0.02`, with `y[1] == 0`, which means a proper initial condition may be near `0`, so I go on trying:

```
midpoint = 0; step = 1/10; 
try@Range[midpoint - 9 step, midpoint + 9 step, step] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The best condition we found is still `y[1] == 0` but the scope is smaller now… wait, so far I was modifying `midpoint` and `step` by hand, why not make them modified automatically?:

```
Clear[leftboundary, area]
(* leftboundary is used for the extraction 
   of the left boundary of the interpolating function,
   it's specifically designed for the structure of try[i]. *)
leftboundary = First@First@First@First[x /. Last@#] &;
(* area is used for the generation of possible y[1] *)
area[midpoint_, step_] := Range[midpoint - 9 step, midpoint + 9 step, step]

NestWhile[{First@SortBy[try@area[First@#, #2], leftboundary], #2/10} & @@ # &, 
          {try[0], 1/100}, leftboundary@First@# > 10^-16 &]
```

> ```
> {513/20000, 1.24278*10^-128, 1/1000000}
> ```

OK, this time we get a even better initial condition: `y[1] == 513/20000`.

Comment: by the way, do you have any idea to guess the initial condition, I tried many times, but still can not find such good initial values. thanks

Comment: @user8583 What I used is just method of exhaustion… of course, this can be done automatically with the combination of `Table` and `Nest`, for this part I can add something to my answer tomorrow, but now I'd like to go to bed. :D

Comment: by the way. For your last paragraph which is talking about how to make the search automatically, I am not quite understanding what it means. such as the definition of g and the content inside nestwhile. if you have time, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user8583 Oh, that's a combination of "pure function" and "list manipulation", which are two of the most important parts of the core language of _Mathematica_, you can have a look at the documents of [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and those about [list manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html). Also, you can read through [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121). If you still feel confused after check all these pages, I don't mind to add more explanations to my answer…

Comment: I am trying to understand your last paragraph about how to search the initial condition automatically, would you mind dividing it into a simpler way? sorry for that, thanks

Comment: @3c. I've changed the last part of the code, I think it's easier to understand now. Feel free to ask if you still feel it obscure.

Comment: thanks, but I am still confused with what's #[[1]], and #[[2]], for your last code, which is `nestwhile`, `{First@SortBy[f@h[First@#[[1]], #[[2]]], g], #[[2]]/10} &` acts on `{f[0], 1/100}`, which means `f@h[First@#[[1]], #[[2]]], g]` acts on `f[0]`, and `#[[2]]/10` acts on `1/100`, I am confused. could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @3c. you seem to misunderstand the syntax of `NestWhile`, for the first round of iteration, `#` in the first argument means the second argument of `NestWhile` i.e. `#[[1]]` represents `{f[0], 1/100}[[1]]`, `#[[2]]` represents `{f[0], 1/100}[[2]]` so the calculated expression is `{First@SortBy[f@h[First@f[0], 1/100], g], 1/100/10}`.

Comment: that's where my confusion. Thank you. By the way, because you notice the initial condition is around `i=0`, what if you do not know that, can you start from any `i` and find the right initial value?

Comment: @3c. I'm sorry that I can't think out a efficient algorithm which can start from any `i` so far… But also notice that the rough range for the current algorithm can be quite extensive. (What I used is $[-10, 10]$ at beginning.)

Comment: thanks anyway. my current problem is for any boundary point instead of `0`, I need to find the initial condition `i`. I have no idea to figure it out